# animation of rotating an image on android

Tags: android, animation

I have doubts on how to make an image rotate like this:

[Expected animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW3ly.gif)

[used icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgRUE.jpg)

I looked in some forums, and what I found helped me get to this point:

[what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKm1n.gif)

```
Drawable



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image" >
    </animated-rotate>
```

Can someone help me ?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
Resolution below.

```
Animation a = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.34f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.67f);
    this.startAnimation(a);
    a.setRepeatCount(-1);
    a.setDuration(680);
```

**Xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Imageview
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:typeSpinner="default-spinner" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make anim folder then create rotate xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><rotate
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="720" /></set>
```

Apply on Image

```
 final ImageView rotate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lolo);
    final Animation rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    rotate.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Comment: I got almost the same result.